# Enable chrome extension without clicking

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, onclick

How to enable chrome extension without clicking it.

I need to perform a certain function from my extension every time i reload a page(no clicking) 
is there a way to do it.

My code which contains the on click method

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
  if (request.action == "getSource") {
    message.innerText = request.source;
  }
});

function onWindowLoad() {

  var message = document.querySelector('#message');

  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: "getPagesSource.js"
  }, function() {
    // If you try and inject into an extensions page or the webstore/NTP you'll get an error
    if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
      message.innerText = 'There was an error injecting script : \n' + chrome.extension.lastError.message;
    }
  });

}

window.onload = onWindowLoad;
```

and

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: started(document)
});
```

Comment: Which function is the function you want to immediately execute?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To include jQuery:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        /*all your normal JavaScript (or include as link)*/
    </script>
</head>
```

Using only pure JavaScript you can do this with:

```
window.onload = function(){/*your JavaScript code*/};
```

only the code within that function will be immediately executed.

In jQuery you can wrap the code you want executed upon loading of page inside of `$(document).ready(function(){`, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*code goes here*/
});
```

`$(document).ready()` checks for when a page is loaded enough to have functionality.

Comment: well, i am not asking about jquery btu thanks anyways

Comment: You can use `window.onload = function(){/*your JavaScript code*/};` without jQuery, as well as `(function(){
/*your JavaScript code*/
}());`

Comment: Could you please tell me why it is not working, then I could find a solution. I am doing the right thing though aren't I, in trying to come up with a function that executes immediately upon loading the page? Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: I have my manifest my js file and an html. Well when i put your code in my js file it just didn't work. Nothing happened, accepted for the hard work

Comment: You need to link your html to the jQuery library as well, did you do that?

Comment: Also the instant startup code must be first code within document.